# Forward and mask a WordPress website

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping, network-admin

I have a WordPress website hosted on GoDaddy on this domain: `theaccountantmalta.com`, we've set up a Parked Domain so that the domain used is `theaccountant.org.mt`.

I've asked GoDaddy if it's possible to have users always on `theaccountant.org.mt` when navigating the website rather than be linked back to the other domain. The reply I got was that WordPress is domain specific so links will remain pointing to `theaccountantmalta.com`. But I can set up forwarding with masking to solve this.

What I've done so far is change the WordPress's settings `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` to `http://theaccountant.org.mt`. This does solve the issue but I'm not sure if it's the best way or if there are other solutions.

I know there are a number of plugins ([WPMU](http://premium.wpmudev.org/)) that handle this stuff but from what I've seen you have to have a WordPress Network or MultiSite enabled to use them, I'm not sure if I need this in my case really.

Comment: "but I'm not sure if it's the best way or if there are other solutions." I personally don't know of another way, my knowledge is lacking there, but what I do know is that Wordpress made it real easy, and you've just done it. Why try to reinvent the wheel when it is already been invented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects to site's URL in WP (baseline case, multisite aside):

1. Which URL it considers "real", responds to, and uses to generate links.
2. URLs previously generated and persistently stored in content.

Former is pretty malleable and as you discovered already is simply a matter of configuration. More so it's technically easy (and practically useful in some cases) to have URL configured on the fly, depending on incoming request. Note that you shouldn't have multiple domains pointing to same site/content in productionm it will likely be penalized by search engines as duplicate content.

If you want to migrate site to different URL (and got your server responding at it) the complete list would be:

1. Changing URL configuration (what you had done already).
2. Updating URLs in content (which is typically done with database search/replace tool, note it should be serialize-aware one to be used reliably with WP).
3. Redirect old URLs to new ones (commonly done at web server level with `.htaccess` or otherwise).

Also see [Changing The Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) in Codex.